# Selenium Automation save file to directory

Tags: python, selenium, automation, pyautogui

I'm working on a selenium script that saves a file from a browser. The script works fine but I'm having difficulties in automation. If the user is logged in the script will run as intended. If the screen is locked or the user is logged out, it can't find the directory.

The script appears to break when saving a file to a directory.

I created a function that uses PyAutoGui to save a file to a designated directory:

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','s')
time.sleep(2)
FILE_NAME = '' + directory + filename
pyautogui.typewrite(FILE_NAME)
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.press('enter')
time.sleep(1)
pyautogui.keyDown('left')
pyautogui.keyDown('enter')
```

The function runs and consoles out that the task has been completed, but the file doesn't actually save to the directory.

I'm assuming that this is due to the directory path being blocked from being modified while the computer is in sleep mode or logged out.

Just to clarify the script runs as intended, only run into this problem when trying to automate the job without a user being present.

Not sure if there is a different way to access a directory. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Doing this with pyautogui is a little overkill. If you are looking for downloading a file - this file is going to have a link which you can get with selenium but then you can use curl/requests to download the file.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add additional parameters in Driver initialization

1. set default download dir
2. turn off prompt to select file location

In case of Chrome, you should configure the following parameters

```
      "download.default_directory": "DIR",
      "download.prompt_for_download": false,
      "download.directory_upgrade": true
```

You can find more details here:
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities (section Set download directory)

Using that approach, the only thing that you have to do is to click on download link.